# Neptune: feature similar to Alias switching in ElasticSearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-neptune

I have a Elasticsearch and Neptune database, only graph relations are store in Neptune.

I'm doing "Alias Switching" in ES, is there a feature like this in Neptune?

Comment: What are you looking to alias exactly in Neptune? In ES I see an alias as a kind of shortcut name to an index or stream. Are you looking to alias the cluster DNS itself or something else?

Comment: I want  to setup alias to a collection of vertex.

Comment: There is nothing quite like that in Gremlin but you could use a `PartitionStrategy` to indicate certain vertices are part of a group. This essentially is syntactic sugar around adding a property to each vertex of the form `'group':'g1'` If that sounds useful I can add an example in an answer.